# Puppet Gluster Volume Error

Tags: puppet, glusterfs

I am getting this error when I add a gluster volume and run puppet agent -t:

Error: Could not retrieve catalog from remote server: Error 500 on SERVER: Server Error: Evaluation Error: Error while evaluating a Resource Statement, Evaluation Error: Error while evaluating a Function Call, 'split' parameter 'str' expects a String value, got Undef at `/etc/puppetlabs/code/environments/test/modules/gluster/manifests/volume.pp:180:21 at /etc/puppetlabs/code/environments/test/manifests/classes/gluster/test_volume.pp:3 on node gluster1.example.com`
Warning: Not using cache on failed catalog
Error: Could not retrieve catalog; skipping run

Below is what I have for test_volume.pp:

    `gluster::volume { 'Test':
        replica => 4,
        bricks  => [
          'gluster1.example.com:/data/test/brick',
          'gluster2.example.com:/data/test/brick',
          'gluster3.example.com:/data/test/brick',
          'gluster4.example.com:/data/test/brick',
          'gluster5.example.com:/data/test/brick',
          'gluster6.example.com:/data/test/brick',
          'gluster7.example.com:/data/test/brick',
          'gluster8.example.com:/data/test/brick',
      ],
      require => [
        File['/data/test'],`

What I'm I doing wrong, I can't seem to figure out why its complaining on those lines.

Comment: is the trailing `\`` on the gluster2 line a typo here or is it in file?

Comment: It's a typo here. sorry.

Comment: ok, maybe try it without the trailing comma on the gluster8 line.  puppet has been fussy about that in the past, maybe it still is.

Comment: It didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

The name of the volume needs to be lower case as when puppet fact for the module I am using for gluster is run, it looks for lowercase in the volume name so if the volume name is upper case you will experience the error I was seeing.